# sort numerically in unix/ linux where "sort -V" not available

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, sed

I am want to sort below shown lines in a file numerically. it is not coming as expected.

```
$ cat test
abc1
abc10
abc2
abc11
abc20
abcd1
abcd10
abcd2
abcd11
abcd20
$
```

Output:-

```
$ sort test
abc1
abc10
abc11
abc2
abc20
abcd1
abcd10
abcd11
abcd2
abcd20
$
```

Output Expected:-

```
abc1
abc2
abc10
abc11
abc20
abcd1
abcd2
abcd10
abcd11
abcd20
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `sort -V` for alphanumeric sorting where numbers are part of string.

```
-V, --version-sort          natural sort of (version) numbers within text

sort -V test
abc1
abc2
abc10
abc11
abc20
abcd1
abcd2
abcd10
abcd11
abcd20
```

Comment: $ sort -V test
sort: invalid option -- V
Try `sort --help' for more information.
$

Comment: it worked in rhel 6.5 whereas in rhel 5.8 "-V" option not available